# How to 'simulate' a Fn key

Tags: keyboard, laptop

I want to 'simulate' a Fn key of an ASUS laptop running Ubuntu when using a normal external keyboard. How can I do this?

Comment: Fn key combinations send diverse events, most of them are not keyboard events. You can set a shortcut key to trigger a similar event or function. What is the function that you want to trigger? What desktop environment are you using, if any?

Answer (score 3):

If your laptop keyboard has a Fn + F1 combination which triggers some action, then you cannot expect the same combination to be available on an external keyboard. The Fn modifier is handled by the keyboard controller inside the laptop, you cannot copy this behavior to the external keyboard.

What you can do is attaching an action for some keyboard shortcut (say, <kbd>Super</kbd> + <kbd>C</kbd>). This can be done in various ways, but your desktop environment typically provides some configuration module where you can set such shortcuts.